# Different use for WordPress Multisite

Tags: multisite

Is there a way to use WordPress Multisite to collaborate all subsites into the main site?

My thought is to have all the subsites to be departments of an organization and the main site be the front page for the organization. Navigation would be created automagically: one for the main site, then a separate navigation that would list the departments (subsites) with drop downs for the pages of those sites.

I'm sure this could all be scripted to work, but I'm curious if there's a solution already out there to roll with right out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible. And there are a few plugins to help make it easier

**[Diamon Multisite Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/diamond-multisite-widgets/)**

> Bloglist, recent posts and comments from the whole network.

**[Wordpress MU Sitewide Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/)**

> A central area where all the posts on a WordPress MU or WordPress MS site can be collected.
>
> This plugin creates a new blog on your server for all the posts on your site, much like http://wordpress.com/tags/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no solution which works out of the box. It can be built using the WordPress blogs database table to get all active blogs. Using this you may get all pages per site and display them in a dropdown. This probably only works on sites with not too much subsites and pages.